# Adding cookies to GET Request not showing

Tags: cookies, jersey

I am trying to add a cookie onto a GET request that contains a token. I tried the following:

```
WebTarget wt = client.target(url).path(path);
wt.queryParam(binaryRepsonse, binaryResponse)
    .request(new MediaType[] {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE})
    .cookie("session", userCredential)
    .get(InputStream.class);
```

However, it doesn't seem to be adding any cookies.
Any pointers?

Comment: How do you know know it's not adding it? Have you inspected the raw request?

Comment: To check, I use my browser and use developer tools. Is there a specific way to check?

Comment: I also tried `Invocation.Builder test = wt.queryParam(..)
                    .request(..)
                    .cookie("session", userCredential)` then `test.get().getCookies()` and apparently that's returning an empty map.

Comment: How do you check with your browser? You are sending a client request to the server. Where does the browser fit into this? The server is supposed to send the initial Set-Cookie to the client. The client sends this cookie back to the server. I think you may have a misunderstanding of how cookies are supposed to be implemented.

Comment: Ah, perhaps. When you say, "inspect the raw request" how can I do this?

Comment: To check: I go to "inspect -> Application -> Cookies".

Comment: I reformatted my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512611/jersey-equivalent-to-httpurlconnection.